# PopToRootViewController in one tab bar item from another tab bar item

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have TabBarViewController with 5 TabBarItem

When I stand at TabBarItem[0], I push to a ViewController by Navigation.
From that ViewController, I switch to TabBarItem[4].
The question is: How can I PopToRootViewController in TabBarItem[0] when I stand at TabBarItem[4]?

Thank you so much.

(My main problem is I have a warning when switch from TabBarItem[4] to TabBarItem[0]:

> 【Transition】Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ABCViewController

so I want to PopToRootViewController at TabBarItem[0] when I stand at TabBarItem[4].
If I can do that, above warning will no more appear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidAppear` of tab 4

```
if let first = self.tabBarController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController {
    // popToRoot here
    first.popToRootViewController(animated:false)
}
```